# Did the Earth government ever recover or build museums around human spacefaring efforts?

Tags: star-trek

Did the Human governments, or the Federation, ever recover the other Voyager probes, or the various landers sent to Mars in Moon and if they did what did they do to them?

Comment: Poor Pioneer; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pioneer_10

Comment: @Valorum wait that was pioneer 10, but it wouldn't have made it that far. I'd figure they would have been recovered considering they'd only be less than a light year away from Earth during the events of the show.

Comment: Wormholes are funny things....

Comment: The *Phoenix* was in the Smithsonian, does that count?  Or are you only interested in real-world spacecraft?

Comment: I don't know about these venerable antiques, but the Federation does acknowledge history.  In "Relics" (ST:TNG), Picard and Scotty share a drink on the holo-deck replica of the Enterprise.  Picard nods "Constitution Class." "Are ye familiar with them?"  "There's one in the fleet museum."  Kinda boggles my mind.  It's not my impression Picard is referring to a holo-deck display in a museum, but an actual ship.  This fleet museum has to occupy a serious volume of space!  And I daresay there would be room for honouring all the earliest days of space exploration.

Comment: The bar in San Francisco shown in Enterprise episodes has space shuttle mission patches displayed.

Comment: I don't know about the series, but one of the novels makes reference to the entirety of Tranquility Base being glassed off (or perhaps transparent aluminumed off) to preserve Armstrong and Aldrin's footprints.

Answer (score 4):

There are the **[Starfleet Museum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fleet_Museum)**:

> The Fleet Museum (or the Starfleet Museum), was a museum on Earth, originally run by the United Earth Starfleet, and later the Federation, in which historic vessels or notable objects were placed on display following their decommissioning.

which housed the *NX-class Enterprise*, and the **[Smithsonian Institution](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Smithsonian_Institution)**:

> The Smithsonian Institution was a collection of museums and research organizations, many of which were located in the city of Washington, DC on Earth. It was initially formed in 1846 in the United States of America, for the "diffusion of knowledge amongst men."

which is known to have the *Phoenix* in its collection.

Besides that, *Star Trek* is supposed to be set in our future, so in lack of any explicit reference of their closing/destruction/relocation, I think that we can safely assume that real existing Science and Technology museums that we have right now are also present in the franchise.